# How to read response after Posting data to server using Retrofit v2 library

Tags: android, retrofit

I am working on Retrofit v2 library for network calls.I am using following dependencies in build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

**1.User.java**

```
    public class User {
    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**2.MyAPI.java**

```
 public interface MyAPI {
    @GET("{roomID}")
    Call<List<Message>>loadMessages(@Path("roomID") String roomID);

    @POST("almabay_oauth/authorize")
    Call<User>login(@Body User user);
}
```

**3.MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String roomID = "548b737c0eadfb00eb93891bb28242e5";
MyAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
List<Message> items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://pms.vebific.com:81/chat/index/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyAPI myAPI = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
    Call<List<Message>> call = myAPI.loadMessages(roomID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Message>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            // Log.e("ResponseP", String.valueOf(response.body()));
            List<Message> items = response.body();
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Message message = (Message) iterator.next();
                String user = message.getUser();
                //Log.e("User", user);
            }
            int statusCode = response.code();
            //Log.e("StatusCode", String.valueOf(statusCode));
            adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });


    //--------------POST-------------

    Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://phpstack-11819-25991-62288.cloudwaysapps.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    MyAPI myPostApi = retrofit1.create(MyAPI.class);
    User user = new User("j@yahoo.com", "Admin123#");
    Call<User> call1 = myPostApi.login(user);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.e("Response code ", String.valueOf(response.code()));
            User user1 = response.body();
            Log.e("Response Message",response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

I have succesfully handled GET request method using this library but i am not able to understand how to read the response after posting data to server using this library.Here i am sending email ID and password to server using Retrofit library.I am getting the status code as 200 here.It means everything is working fine.I know after posting data to server successfully,i am getting some response string .But here i am unable to view the response.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

as you said you got response code 200 it means there is no issue with your request and response.

use OkHttpLoggingIntercepter class.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
```

you will get detailed log of your response and all the errors if any.

**one more thing** Gson Converter only parse json data which has json object at root. not JsonArray.

so check your response string as well in log by writing above code.

Answer (score 0):

try to send this `POST` request via `Postman` plugin for Chrome, maybe your User class is wrong

Comment: Everything is working fine when I am posting data using RestClient in Chrome.Data is submitted to server successfully and I am getting the required response.

Comment: @DeepakR can you provide response?

Comment: I am working on mobile now.But I am very much sure that I am getting Json response after successful posting data.As you can see,inside onResponse () method, I am using response.body() which gives me variable of type User class.Now User class contain data to be posted to server I.e. emailID and password.Now my question is how can I get the response? DO I need to create any POJO class for Response?I am confused here.

Comment: @DeepakR Of course you need create POJO for response

Comment: Ok.But response.body() is giving me data of type User class.Please explain in detail.

Comment: @DeepakR that's why i said provide please json response

Comment: When i am using response.body() method ,i am getting value of type User class where User class is having fields containing data to be posted to server.So i am confused here how to receive the response.